# jQuery : Remove Class from immediate 'uncles'

Tags: jquery

I am making a form that is split into sections. Each section is in its own DIV that has the class of option.

The form consists of radio input buttons that are wrapped in a label. (The label HAS to wrap the input for compatibility reasons in IE8)*. When the user clicks on an input button, I want to use jQuery to add a 'tick' class to the parent wrapper label. I also want to remove the tick class from any adjacent parent labels (i.e. uncles) that are not the immediate parent label. However, I only want this removal to occur in the immediate section and not in other sections.

How can I do this? I thought I could achieve it with the jQuery function 'closest' but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8Kae/)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="daddyhair hairstyle hairoption option">
    <label for="chara2-hairdaddy1" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy1 ticked" >
        <input name="hairstyle" class="chara2-hairdaddy1" id="chara2-hairdaddy1" type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy1" checked="checked" />
    </label>
    <label for="chara2-hairdaddy2" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy2">
        <input name="hairstyle"  id="chara2-hairdaddy2"   type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy2" />
    </label>
    <label for="chara2-hairdaddy3" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy3">
        <input name="hairstyle"  id="chara2-hairdaddy3"   type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy3" />
    </label>
    <label for="chara2-hairdaddy4" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy4">
        <input name="hairstyle" id="chara2-hairdaddy4"   type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy4" />
    </label>
    <label for="chara2-hairdaddy5" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy5 ">
        <input name="hairstyle"   id="chara2-hairdaddy5"  type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy5" />
    </label>
    <label  for="chara2-hairdaddy6" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy6 ">
        <input name="hairstyle"   id="chara2-hairdaddy6"  type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy6" />
    </label>
    <label  for="chara2-hairdaddy7" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy7 " >
        <input name="hairstyle" id="chara2-hairdaddy7"  type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy7" />
    </label>
    <label  for="chara2-hairdaddy8" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy8 ">
        <input name="hairstyle"   id="chara2-hairdaddy8"  type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy8" />
    </label>
    <label  for="chara2-hairdaddy9" onclick="" class="chara2-hairdaddy9 ">
        <input name="hairstyle"   id="chara2-hairdaddy9"  type="radio" value="chara2-hairdaddy9" />
    </label>
</div>

       <div class="daddymoustache moustachestyle hairoption option">
          <label for="chara2-moustachedaddy1" onclick=""  class="chara2-moustachedaddy1 ticked">
            <input name="moustachestyle"  id="chara2-moustachedaddy1" type="radio" value="chara2-moustachedaddy1" checked="checked" />
          </label>
          <label for="chara2-moustachedaddy2" onclick="" class="chara2-moustachedaddy2" >
            <input name="moustachestyle"  id="chara2-moustachedaddy2"   type="radio" value="chara2-moustachedaddy2" />
          </label>
          <label for="chara2-moustachedaddy3" onclick=""  class="chara2-moustachedaddy3">
            <input name="moustachestyle"  id="chara2-moustachedaddy3"   type="radio" value="chara2-moustachedaddy3" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="daddysideburn sideburnstyle hairoption option">
          <label for="chara2-sideburndaddy1" onclick="" class="chara2-sideburndaddy1 ticked">
            <input name="sideburnstyle"  id="chara2-sideburndaddy1"   type="radio" value="chara2-sideburndaddy1" />
          </label>
          <label  for="chara2-sideburndaddy2" onclick="" class="chara2-sideburndaddy2 ">
            <input name="sideburnstyle"   id="chara2-sideburndaddy2"  type="radio" value="chara2-sideburndaddy2" />
          </label>
        </div>
```

The code posted in JSFiddle is abbreviated. The full code makes use of CSS backgrounds, which wont work in IE8 if the input is not wrapped in the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

I changed your code a little, instead of detecting clicks on input, detect click on labels itself.

```
$("label").click(function()
{
    $(this).siblings("label.ticked").removeClass('ticked');
    $(this).addClass('ticked');
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x8Kae/1/)**